# If X is $\overline{\sigma(Y)}$-measureable, then X is already $\sigma(Y)$-measureable a.s.?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a complete probability space, $X$ an $E$-valued r.v. and $Y$ an $F$-valued r.v. for polish spaces $E,F$. Is the following assertion true?

If $X$ $\overline{\sigma(Y)}$-measureable, then $X$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measureable almost surely.

By $\overline{\sigma(Y)}$ we denote the completed sigma algebra. I think this is used in my script in the context of strong solutions for SDE's(see my last question). I would be very grateful for hints or a solution.

Comment: The question you have posed is the converse of the one in the title. Also, you are expected to show what you have done so far.

Comment: **Hint:** $\sigma (Y)\subset \overline{\sigma (Y)}$

Comment: Oh sorry, I corrected the title.

Comment: Note $\sigma(Y)$ is a sigma-algebra in $\Omega$, the domain of $Y$.  So trivially we cannot omit the "almost surely" part.  Not so trivially, this can fail where $Y$ is not a Polish space, or something like it.

Comment: What is meant by “measurable almost surely”?

Answer (score 2):

Not a solution.  A careful restatement of the problem.  I think.

---

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space,
let $E$ and $F$ be Polish spaces.

Let $X : \Omega \to E$ be $\big(\mathcal F, \mathcal B(E)\big)$-measurable
[where $\mathcal B(E)$ is the sigma-algebra of Borel sets in $E$].
Let $Y : \Omega \to F$ be $\big(\mathcal F, \mathcal B(F)\big)$-measurable.
Write
$$
\mathcal G = \sigma(Y) = \big\{Y^{-1}(U) \mid U \in \mathcal B(F)\big\}
$$
The $\mathbb P$-completion of $\mathcal G$ is
$$
\overline{\mathcal G} =
\big\{K \subseteq \Omega \mid \exists A,B \in \mathcal G,
A \subseteq K \subseteq B, \mathbb P(B\setminus A) = 0 \big\} .
$$
Assume $\mathcal F$ is $\mathbb P$-complete.  That is, $\overline{\mathcal F} = \mathcal F$.
Assume $X$ is also $\big(\overline{\mathcal G},\mathcal B(E)\big)$-measurable.
**To prove:**  There exists $X_1 : \Omega \to E$ such that
$X_1$ is $\big(\mathcal G,\mathcal B(E)\big)$-measurable and
$\mathbb P\big\{\omega\in \Omega \mid X(\omega) \ne X_1(\omega)\big\} = 0$.

Comment: +1 Thanks for posting this. It made me realise that I had this problem backwards, so I deleted my answer.

Comment: I will post an answer in a few days, if no one else does.